# Striped obj/gltf

Tags: modeling, svg, gltf

I am pretty new to blender.. I tried to make a logo from an SVG. I extruded the SVG and turned it into a mesh. But, I get this striped effect on the model when I export it... Why is this? I tried to perform a mesh clean up but hasn't helped[image: striped model]

Comment: that looks like it might be z-fighting: two surfaces are in the same place and the render engine doesn't know which to use.  It might also be a lighting artifact.  Could you add your blend file to your question (([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) or at least include screen shots showing the wire frame of the text; the material nodes; and the outliner with all entries expanded?

Comment: It may also help to [recalculate normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html#recalculate).